# How to sync microcontroller to MIDI controller output

Tags: midi

I am looking to receive MIDI messages to control a microcontroller based synthesizer and I am working on understanding the MIDI protocol so I may implement a MIDI handler. I've read MIDI is transmitted at 31.25kHz without a dedicated clock line - must I sample the line at 31.25kHz with the microcontroller in order to receive MIDI bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> The hardware MIDI interface operates at 31.25 (+/- 1%) Kbaud, asynchronous, with a start bit, 8 data bits (D0 to D7), and a stop bit. […] Bytes are sent LSB first.

This describes a standard UART protocol; you can simply use the UART hardware that most microcontrollers have built in. (The baud rate of 31250 Hz was chosen because it can be easily derived from a 1 Mhz (or multiple) clock.)

If you really wanted to implement the receiver in software, you would sample the input signal at a higher rate to able to reliably detect the level in the middle of each bit; for details, see [What exactly is the start bit error in UART?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/91450) and [How does UART know the difference between data bits and start/stop bits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/251341)